# Latex editor with Git integration

Tags: windows, git, ide

I am looking for a LaTeX IDE for Windows 10.

I see that only TexStudio has an SVN/Git option in the menu. However, it is unable to checkout from BitBucket.

Which LaTeX IDE is freeware, has a built-in Git integration, and is able to compile and show live PDF?

Comment: Emacs can do everything you ask for and is very powerful. But it has a steep learning curve.

Comment: @TeXnician, I am a Windows user.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Yes? Emacs is multiplatform. Of course it has its roots on unix but today's emacs is perfectly usable on Windows. The steep learning curve remains independent of the platform.

Comment: @TeXnician, Its not an IDE..

Comment: Emacs runs on Windows. And even Windows users can learn how to handle this beast!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) There are plenty of editors in this list that have Git support. Probably the most popular these days is VS Code.

Comment: @user366312 It is an IDE for pretty much anything once you load some packages. For instance, with TeXlab and LSP it has awesome IDE features and much better text editing support. But we can stop this discussion here, you don't seem to like it and that's okay, I just commented that it could fulfill your points. But I'm sure someone else will throw in a less comprehensive tool :)

Comment: Atom is a possibility. It is very customizable by plugins and it has by default installed git plugin. It allows to fetch, pull, push and everything else

Comment: @TeXnician obligatory cult-response: Don't use Emacs, instead use a decent editor like VIM!